# Can any remote be used with an RC car?

Tags: remote-control

I just bought [this awesome H2 Hummer RC](http://support.radioshack.com/support_games/doc71/71672.pdf) for $2 at a garage sale (the battery alone that was inside is worth about $100.). The motor works fine and the car is in excellent shape but it did not come with a remote to control the car. Is it possible to just buy any remote to control the car? How would I get it to work with this hummer?

Comment: Questions of the use of electronic devices are off-topic in this forum.  This has nothing to do with electronic design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to use just any remote with this R/C car.
Common frequencies used are 27mhz or 49mhz[[1](http://rcvehicles.about.com/od/frequency/a/frequencychoice.htm)]. A [parts list](http://support.radioshack.com/support_games/doc71/71320.htm) for this toy lists crystals with a frequency of 26-27mhz, so I would start my search with a couple of remotes that transmit on that frequency, and see if any of them work. You might want to check a place like Hobbytown for a replacement controller, but I doubt that they would have one at a good price.

Comment: So do you think something like this would work? http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-Radio-Remote-Control-AM-27mHz-Transmitter-Receiver-for-1-10-RC-Car-/171728747971?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item27fbd4bdc3

Comment: @MichaelRader I really have no idea, it's one of those things you're just going to have to play with. They're so many different standards out there for radio control it's hard to say.